# Pasar todos los nombres de las columna de inglés a español

Tags: python

Estoy intentando pasar todos los nombres de las columna de inglés a español

```
!pip install google_trans_new
```

```py
from google_trans_new import google_translator

translator = google_translator()
translated = google_translator.translate(df[['Unnamed: 0', '_id', 'mainVehicle', 'vehicleImg', 'campaignImg',
       'secondaryImages', 'category', 'features', 'equipmentHtml',
       'mainVehicleBrand', 'mainVehicleModel', 'infoHtml', 'groupName',
       'region', 'hasFlexibleadvantages', 'flexibleadvantages',
       'subscriptionType', 'showBadge', 'catalogIndex', 'isPurchasable',
       'specificvehicleplanversion', 'price', 'isOnOffer', 'offerPrice',
       'allowRemoveExcess', 'removeExcessPrice', 'franchiseValue',
       'reducedFranchiseValue', 'sharedUserPrice', 'commitmentMonths',
       'addons', 'hasSharedSubscriptionsEnabled', 'typedFeatures.transmission',
       'typedFeatures.seats', 'typedFeatures.fuelType', 'typedFeatures.year',
       'typedFeatures.modelVersion', 'typedFeatures.status',
       'typedFeatures.powerCV', 'typedFeatures.engineCapacityCC',
       'contract.kmIncluded', 'contract.extraKmPrice', 'offerBadge.color',
       'offerBadge.badgeText', 'badge.defaultLanguage', 'badge.color',
       'badge.languages']], lang_src='en', lang_tgt='es')

print(translated)
```

Tengo puesto este código pero me sale error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-f5f68da03f66> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 translator = google_translator()
----> 2 translated = google_translator.translate(df[['Unnamed: 0', '_id', 'mainVehicle', 'vehicleImg', 'campaignImg',
      3        'secondaryImages', 'category', 'features', 'equipmentHtml',
      4        'mainVehicleBrand', 'mainVehicleModel', 'infoHtml', 'groupName',
      5        'region', 'hasFlexibleadvantages', 'flexibleadvantages',

TypeError: google_translator.translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Después he hecho lo mismo pero poniendo solo uno

Comment: `translate` espera un texto, tu les estas pasando un dataframe. Has probado a ejecutar la misma instruccion pasandole un string?  Functiona si haces `google_translator.translate("hello", lang_src='en', lang_tgt='es')`? Si functiona entonces el problema esta en que debes convertir primero tu dataframe a string

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede ser que no estás utilizando la instancia que creaste:

```
translated = google_translator.translate(...)
```

Para utilizarla lo haces así:

```
translated = translator.translate(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

No usaste el objeto que creaste "translator"
No soy experto en pandas pero te está diciendo que no le estás pasando texto como argumento.
Proba imprimir ese DF con el método .info o .help y si tenés columnas con otro tipo de valor vas a tener que convertirlas a texto.